# updating software of HTC

Tags: htc-one-v

HTC one V has a special feature of beats audio, but I have not updated its software since I brought it.If I update the software  of HTC one v, will it remove beats audio feature from my mobile

Answer (score 0):

Beats audio is anadvertised as an outstanding feature of top HTC phones.
Why should HTC remove an advertised feature with a software update? Of course will it continue to work. I fail to see why one may question this.